# Matlab installer error: Failed to create the specified folder. To continue, select a different folder

Tags: software-installation, matlab

I'm currently installing Matlab on ubuntu 22.04 and, as announced in the title, when I try to install it in the path /usr/local/MATLAB/R2022a I get the following error:

`Failed to create the specified folder. To continue, select a different folder.`

This I think is due to the fact that if I can't run the installer in sudo mode (it simply does not run the installer, or better, it does not appear the wizard and the terminal continues to wait the end of the command). What are the pros and cons to create a differt path to the installation?

Comment: You probably *should* install it with sudo - you may need to use xhost to give root permission to open your display. See for example [Why can't I install MATLAB with the root account in Linux when the installer works for my user account?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/133944-why-can-t-i-install-matlab-with-the-root-account-in-linux-when-the-installer-works-for-my-user-accou#answer_140586)

Comment: Could you post the exact command that you used?

Comment: @steeldriver that post was very useful. I solved the problem with the command `xhost +SI:localuser:root`. Thank you.